# TypoScript: additional HTML-Template for each Content Element

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I want to create some kind of a blog, and therefor I thought it is clever to create an HTML-Template for each Content Element on a page.

How do I configure the typoscript to "load" an additional HTML-Template for each content element and put data like headline, author, pubDate... into the marks of that html-Template?

Comment: You might want to try the extension ``dce`` or ``gridelements``.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`Extension Builder`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder) extension it will allow you create sample blog extension in several minutes of clicking....

Note: for TYPO3 ver. `4.7.x` use `Extension Builder` with version lower than `2.5.0`, and do TYPO3 ver. 60 just take the newest one.

Comment: In addition: You can find some basic documentation for your first project with the extension builder in the [official wiki](http://wiki.typo3.org/T3Doc/Extension_Builder) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the extension "news" (see http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news). It seems that you're new to TYPO3. Therefore I wouldn't start with programming an own blog extension. For the beginning the before mentioned news extension will pretty much suit your needs.

Creating your own fields and using your own templates is not that easy and doesn't make sense since there are ready build and reliable extensions.